# converting chr() / ord() with multi characters

Tags: python

beginner programming in python (3.4)
is it possible to pass multiple values inside chr() and ord()?
what i tried is the following:

```
userInput = input('Please write your input: ')
> Hello
result = ord(userInput) #here is the error because i put multiple values instead of just one
print(result)
```

this is the output i am looking for: `72 101 108 108 111` (hello) but instead i get an error telling me i can only pass 1 character/value inside chr() / ord()
is this possible? if not can you provide me in the right direction? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension - apply `ord` to each character in the string.

```
In [777]: [ord(i) for i in 'hello']
Out[777]: [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function, in order to apply the `ord` on all characters separately:

```
In [18]: list(map(ord, 'example'))
Out[18]: [101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101]
```

Or use `bytearray` directly on string:

```
In [23]: list(bytearray('example', 'utf8'))
Out[23]: [101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101]
```

But note that when you are dealing with unicodes `bytearray` doesn't return a number like `ord` but an array of bytes values based on the passed encoding (a number between 0 and 256):

```
In [27]: list(bytearray('€', 'utf8'))
Out[27]: [226, 130, 172]

In [25]: ord('€')
Out[25]: 8364
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to apply `ord` to every character of the string, and then join them to get the result you're looking for:

```
result = " ".join([str(ord(x)) for x in userInput])
```